# recursive function how to save messages in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, recursion

I have created recursive function that sorts my nested object, gets messages  from it  depending on some properties. At the end I want to get an array with messages, but when the function iterates itself, it rewrites old array . How to keep pushing messages to an array without loosing previos messages and return that array

I have tried to reproduce my code in jsfidle , but my recursive function runs only once. Anyway if you need an object I'm working with , here is a link  https://jsfiddle.net/armakarma/hvj62una/1/

```
  getMessageFromStage(data, algoritmID, stageIDS) {
    let stage = data[algoritmID][stageIDS]
    let result = []
    let nextStageId = null
    let nextAlgId = null

    // here i'm pushing messages to result array

    if (stage.messages.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < stage.messages.length; i++) {
        if (stage.messages[i].message_type === "text") {
          result.push(stage.messages[i].message)
        }
      }
    }
    if (stage.render === true) {
      nextStageId = stage.stageID
    } else {
      nextStageId = 1
    }
    if (stage.algoritm_id) {
      nextAlgId = stage.algoritm_id
    } else {
      nextAlgId = algoritmID
    }

    if (nextStageId && nextAlgId && stage.render) {
      this.getMessageFromStage(data, nextAlgId, nextStageId)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please simplify the problem, what is your input and desired output, I saw your object data, what you trying to output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least two solutions.

1. Create an outer function that declares `results` and makes the first call to `getMessageFromStage`.

```
myFun(data, algoritmID, stageIDS) {
   const results = [];
   this.getMessageFromStage(data, algoritmID, stageIDS);
   return results;
}
```

2. Make `results` another, optional, argument of `getMessageFromStage`, and pass it along with every recursive call.

```
getMessageFromStage(data, algoritmID, stageIDS, results = []) {
  //...
  if (nextStageId && nextAlgId && stage.render) {
    this.getMessageFromStage(data, nextAlgId, nextStageId, results);
  }
}
```

Comment: second solution is perfect for me! thank you very much